# Google Play Store APK - Device Compatibility Issue

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My app APK is uploaded to the Google Play Store. Surprised to see that the supported devices list shown as  0.

I think this got something to do with the manifest setting. It could well be one of the following features or permissions is having the issue with google play filter . I have specified clearly in the Manifest.xml that only SDK 18 or above is able to run the app .

Contacted Google support, still no answer after almost 120 hours past.

I have seen some suggestions that this may well be the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` setting related issue.

Appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

---

Features

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.hardware.BLUETOOTH
android.hardware.BLUETOOTH_LE
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

Permission

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Comment: Perhaps upper/lower case issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14299962/295004

Comment: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION these are not features,these are permissions which you have to take to get supports.please remove and android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT for this use run time time permission at particular stage .

Comment: I believe nothing to do the upper or lower case as the above was the play store display not on my manifest , I will try to remove the access coarse and fine but I worry the android 6 will be prompting for this to be included during apk generation and I remember I did have a version without this two and yet thing still the same. Portrait this is must , I do not intend to flip to landscape mode . Anyway thanks for the suggestion , google support just response they are  investigate the matter.

Comment: Hi TSG, was wondering where do you see this *0 compatible device* label?

Comment: Al , are you the person work as  google developer engineer , i saw you have reply to my query , basically as what brahmy suggested , I removed all the access coarse, access fin in the features. Permission maintained as it is .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setup on the grade file:
Such as

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.."
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.8"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

It will help you.

Comment: In fact this was also fully stated in the gradle file , still no solution to the issues, yes multidex support is required, as the library is large.