# Google play shows 0 device supported for published app

Tags: android

I don't get the solution of this problem i have tested my code on devices with API level range between 19-25 and my code work well on every device than what make my app 0 supported device on play store?? i talk about it to google also they said something wrong with your manifest file and said :

So for example with Nexus 7, the reason why it's not compatible is because of the following reason. 
Unsupported framework version:
17
No supported native platform:
armeabi, armeabi-v7a

i still don't get the actual problem behind that please some body help me!!

here below is my manifest file content

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my package name">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.Portrait" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
 <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
 <application
        android:name="ABC"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="SomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ......
 </application>
</manifest >
```

here below is my gradle file content:

```
uildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my package name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    //---------for retrofit----------
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
    //---------
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //------------- for auto sliding
    compile group: 'com.nineoldandroids', name: 'library', version: '2.4.0'

    //----- staggered gridview
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    //-----for zooming
    //compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':photoview')

}
```

Comment: Could you please upload your gradle file?

Comment: uploaded my gradle . please help!

Comment: <supports-screens`enter code here" - what is it?

Comment: that is added here by mistake

Comment: I have finally resolve my own problem by removing older version & deprecated libraries from gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be "p"ortrait instead of "P"ortrait

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

Look at this link

[I set uses-feature android:required="false" but Google play keeps insisting on these features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299956/i-set-uses-feature-androidrequired-false-but-google-play-keeps-insisting-on-t)